# Typed Racket string->number how to convert result to integer

Tags: scheme, racket, typed

I am trying to convert a project over from Racket to Typed Racket and I am encountering some issues with the typing mechanisms.

string->number returns (U Complex False), but I cannot find any procedures to convert that (or even just a Complex) to an Integer.

A very short example that illustrates my issue:

```
#language typed/racket

(define die : Integer 5)

(define dlist '("1" "2" "3" "4" "5"))

(set! die (string->number (car dlist)))
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `string->number` has the type `(U Complex False)`, where a value of `false` means `string->number` failed to parse a number. In this case you know for sure that it won't fail, so you can just assert that it is an integer with `(assert (string->number ...) exact-integer?)`:

```
#lang typed/racket

(define die : Integer 5)

(define dlist '("1" "2" "3" "4" "5"))

(set! die (assert (string->number (car dlist)) exact-integer?))
```

I understand that it's supposed to be a simple example but try to stick with numbers and avoid strings if you can.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will test it tonight. I needed to use strings because in the real program i am accepting user input. (Typed on iPhone. Sorry for formatting(

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem. I should mention that this works in general when you have something like `(U Foobar False)`. You can read more about this kind of stuff in the [guide](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/occurrence-typing.html).